# huawei push kit: getToken return unknown error code

Tags: push-notification, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

When I try to get use getToken method, it return the 907122050 error code, what is that mean?

```
    try {
      token = HmsInstanceId.getInstance(context).getToken(appId, defaultScope);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
      CoreLogger.e("getToken error: " + e.getStatusCode());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/error-code-0000001050255690#section15969337175715).

[image: HMS Core Push SDK Result Codes]

Result Codes `907122050` indicates the operation cannot be performed in the main thread. The method needs to be created in the subthread.

**Solution**: Need to Create a thread and call a specific method in the new thread.